# Отложенный вывод переменной php

Tags: php, переменные

```
// code ...
echo $sTitle; // Как тут вывести 'Привет!', который инициализируется позже вывода?
// code ...
$sTitle = 'Привет!';
```

Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Конечно же никак. Лучше полностью задачу озвучить, потому как её решение может быть и другим.

Comment: Мы не знаем, что скрывается под `// code ...` Вполне может быть, что все возможно

Comment: Интересует именно такой вариант, полностью задачи нет, интерес существования такого метода. 
Как то через функцию передать значение в уже существующую переменную и вывести?

Comment: если без `// code...` ?

Comment: вот так `function Hi($sTitle) {
echo $sTitle;
}

$sTitle = 'Привет!';
Hi($sTitle);`

Comment: Нет, здесь вывод после инициализации как и полагается, а вопрос о выводе перед инициализацией, как бы с задержкой. 
Всё равно что на js, например, через событие сделать, но там иначе всё.

Comment: дак добавьте сюда вариант кода на JS, для понимания, чего вы хотите. Надо полагать, что вы не совсем понимаете что и когда инициализируется, поэтому думаете, что переменную можно какой-то магией вывести до того, как значение присвоено, но такое не возможно.

Comment: На js такое тоже работать не будет.

Comment: от магии не отказался бы, но хотел выяснить есть ли более приземлённые способы )
на js можно элементарно через `setTimeout` проверять есть ли переменная и если нет, вызывать проверку повторно, этакий цикл пока не будет объявлена

Comment: буферизация, не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно включить буферизацию, расставить якоря, а потом на их место вставить нужные значения

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo '$sTitle';
$sTitle = 'Привет!';
$out=ob_get_clean();
echo str_replace('$sTitle',$sTitle,$out);
```

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, код выше можно заставить работать как вы хотите (хотя не представляю для чего подобное может потребоваться и *лучше так не делать*):

```
$assigned = false;
myLabel:

echo $sTitle;
$sTitle = 'Привет!';

if (!$assigned) {
    $assigned = true;
    goto myLabel;
}
```

При этом, очевидно, мы всё равно увидим предупреждение Undefined variable: sTitle (при соответствующем уровне [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)).

Можно ещё извернуться через само-include:

```
if (!isset($included)) {
    $included = true;
    include __FILE__;
}

echo $sTitle;
$sTitle = 'Привет!';
```

Comment: ого, интересное решение, спасибо! 
не для чего пока не нужно, мне доказывали, что на php так нельзя, я был уверен, что должно быть можно )  сам с php связан только редкими правками в шаблонах bitrix ) 
спасибо за ответ!